# Alignment of page numbers in page footer

Tags: vba, ms-word

I am working on tools  that should check various page setting on (long) word documents. One of the requirements is to check if the footer contains page numbers, and if those page numbers are centered.

I wrote a small piece of code to check the settings:

```
Sub CheckPageNumber()
    Dim footer As HeaderFooter, s As String
    Set footer = ActiveDocument.Sections(1).Footers(wdHeaderFooterPrimary)
    Debug.Print "Has Pagination: " & footer.PageNumbers.Count
    If footer.PageNumbers.Count > 0 Then
        Debug.Print "Alignment = " & footer.PageNumbers(1).Alignment
    End If
End Sub
```

To my surprise I got the result (tested with various documents on 2 different computers)

```
Has Pagination: 1
Alignment = 9999999
```

I can set the alignment with

```
footer.PageNumbers(1).Alignment = wdAlignPageNumberCenter
```

(or any of the other allowed values, which are names constants with the value 0-4), but I cannot set it back to the strange value of 9999999 (throws runtime 9118 - *parameter out of acceptable range*).

The problem is, with that 9999999, I cannot tell if the page number is centered or not - it is not depending on how the page number was added.

Does anybody know what the meaning of this number is, and, more important, how else I can figure out the position of the page number?

Comment: A value of 9999999 typically means Undefined. In this instance it indicates that `PageNumber.Alignment` hasn't been explicitly set and the page number field is inline with text.

Comment: Interesting. Is this documented somewhere? And how do I identify the inline position of the page number? In the `Range.Text` it is represented simply as 1 an I got completely lost when digging into the other `Range` properties.

Comment: For Undefined see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.wdconstants

Comment: Alignment in a footer can be tricky. The page number field could be the only text in the paragraph (easy to check), be in a table, be preceded by a standard tab, or be preceded by an alignment tab.

Comment: Thanks. I will dig into it. Maybe I raise a new question how to identify fields, but first I will try to figure out by my own.

Comment: One more fun complication is that each section in Word has three footers. You are checking one of them. They can all be different. https://www.addbalance.com/usersguide/sections2007.htm#Recap_of_Header/Footer_settings

Comment: Yes, I already know about that and handling it. Although my customer state that they don't use it - but I don't want to leave loopholes.